# Чтение файла кусками с openAL, возможно ли это?

Tags: c++

Допустим есть wav файл ~300 мегабайт, как с помощью openAL грузить например помегабайтно кусок файла и воспроизводить его?

Answer (score 1):

можно, моя ошибка была в том что я пытался воспроизвести первые 44 байта тоже..